# Spark equivalent to postgres json function ->

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to query a json field from Spark to see if one element is set to true.

The content of my json field options looks like this: `"match_tax_type"=>"true", "sales_tax_enabled"=>"true", …`

In postgres, I can evaluate the json like so `where (options -> 'sales_tax_enabled') = 'true'`

Is there an equivalent function in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `get_json_object`

In this case you would have something like:

`.where(get_json_object(col("json"), "$.key") === "true")`

References:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#get_json_object-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-most-used-json-functions-with-examples/#get_json_object